# How do I undo the most recent transformation performed on QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsView, which contains rectangle, polyline, text etc. I also have some features to transform the view like zoom in, zoom out, Fit in view, change the color on mouse right click etc.  I want to add few more features like `Undo` and `Redo`.

> Undo means, user should cancel the effect of last command executed and
> show previous transformation. So If user did transformation like zoom
> in -> zoom in -> fit in -> zoom in and now pressed Undo then view's
> fit in position should get displayed.

How to think about this ? Should I store each transformation of view somewhere, say in stack ? But how to store each transformation in stack ? I am clueless. Can anyone help me to think ?

Comment: Wrap `QTransform` in `QUndoCommand`?

Comment: Zoom and Colour changes are very different.  So "etc" makes the category described unclear.